# GCP PubSub to GCS dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-storage

I have one use case to create files in GCS buckets from PubSub with the below conditions:

1. Window size limit
2. Published message size to PubSub topic exceeds 500MB

For eg,
i) If we specify window size as 15 mins, and the messages published to PubSub exceeds 500MB before the window size of 15 mins, then we can load data to GCS buckets
ii) If the messages published to PubSub does not exceed 500MB even after the window size of 15 mins, then it that case too, it should start data load to GCS Bucket since the window size is reached.

Can anyone please help me with code reference for the above use case?

I tried creating a function to get the size of messages published to PubSub but unable to get the size

Comment: You probably need Composite triggers
: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#composite-triggers

Answer (score 0):

Posting @[XQ Hu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21289117/xq-hu) recommendation as an wiki for better visibility for the community,  Using Composite Triggers for this use case:

> You probably need Composite triggers :
>
> https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#composite-triggers

Types of triggers:

> - You can add additional early firings or late firings to `AfterWatermark.pastEndOfWindow` via `.withEarlyFirings` and `.withLateFirings`.
> - `Repeatedly.forever` specifies a trigger that executes forever. Any time the trigger’s conditions are met, it causes a window to emit results and then resets and starts over. It can be useful to combine `Repeatedly.forever` with `.orFinally` to specify a condition that causes the repeating trigger to stop.
> - `AfterEach.inOrder` combines multiple triggers to fire in a specific sequence. Each time a trigger in the sequence emits a window, the sequence advances to the next trigger.
> - `AfterFirst` takes multiple triggers and emits the first time any of its argument triggers is satisfied. This is equivalent to a logical OR operation for multiple triggers.
> - `AfterAll` takes multiple triggers and emits when all of its argument triggers are satisfied. This is equivalent to a logical AND operation for multiple triggers.
> - `orFinally` can serve as a final condition to cause any trigger to fire one final time and never fire again.